# Will I lose WSL data if I disable HyperV?

Tags: hyper-v, vmware-workstation, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Will I lose WSL data if I disable HyperV? I need to use VMware, but I have some data on WSL. Also I Have Win 10 Home

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: It looks like you can actually just go on using WSLv2 with VMWare, as long as it's a recent version! VMWare now supports Hyper-V compatibility including for WSL. See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-faq#will-i-be-able-to-run-wsl-2-and-other-3rd-party-virtualization-tools-such-as-vmware-or-virtualbox and https://blogs.vmware.com/workstation/2020/01/vmware-workstation-tech-preview-20h1.html

---

Assuming you're using WSLv2 - which has been the default for a while now but is still much newer than v1 - you might lose easy access to that data. WSLv2 is implemented using virtual machines, and uses actual Linux file systems mounted on a virtual disk file. WSLv1 is implemented directly on NTFS and the NT kernel and does not use any virtualization software. Run `wsl -l -v` in a Windows command line terminal to see what version of WSL you're currently using.

The VHDX (Virtual Hard Disk file) for a WSLv2 distro would still exist even if you disabled Hyper-V, and in theory could be mounted and read (Windows supports mounting VHDX files like physical disks, and there are also third-party programs that can read them). However, you'd need an appropriate file system driver - third-party Linux file system drivers are available for Windows but not included by default - and you definitely wouldn't be able to use the usual methods of accessing WSL through Windows file paths.

Your better option would be to convert your WSL to version 1. WSLv1 does not use a VM, instead it's more like Wine (in reverse), adding an ELF program loader and Linux syscall support (with path translation, etc.) to Windows and running the Linux software directly on the NT kernel rather than on a virtualized Linux kernel.

To do this, open any Windows command line (Powershell, CMD, etc.) and run `wsl --set-version <Distro> 1` where <Distro> is whatever WSL distro you have installed (run `wsl -l` to list them); it's probably something like `Ubuntu`. You can also then run `wsl --set-default-version 1` to make WSL avoid creating v2 (virtualized) WSL distros in the future, if you ever install another one.

Note that converting a WSLv2 distro to v1 takes a while - the process is basically "start WSLv2, copy every file other than stuff like the kernel out of it into a special directory on the host NTFS drive, and change some metadata" and one of the downsides of WSLv1 is that writing WSL files to NTFS is slow due to all the translating that goes on - but it should work *as long as you do it before disabling Hyper-V*. Once it's done, you can safely disable Hyper-V (as long as you weren't using it for anything else, such as some Windows security features that rely on it, but since you're running Home edition that is unlikely).

A perk of doing this is that you'll not only retain access to the WSL data, you'll continue to be able to use WSL to run Linux programs. Anything that requires an actual Linux kernel (like drivers for hardware or file systems, or other kernel modules) won't work, networking will be a little different (it'll just share the Windows networking interface rather than using a virtualized one), file I/O performance and possibly some other things will be different and mostly for the worse... but it'll be better integrated with the Windows OS, allowing you to do things like pipe a Windows command into a Linux command directly.

If the converting to v1 route doesn't appeal, you can also export a distro to a tarball, which can be opened using Windows software. However, this will take about the same time as converting the distro - possibly longer, because it'll include stuff like the kernel - without leaving the WSL files actually on the file system anywhere. To do this, use `wsl --export <Distro> <Filename>`. Remember that this is a Windows command, so the file name should be using a Windows path.

You can run `wsl --help` for more info on the `wsl.exe` command-line tool and its options. You might also want to read https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/compare-versions and https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-faq.

Comment: Ubuntu-20.04           Stopped         V1

Comment: So I Can Disable HyperV

Comment: @PutoPug Yeah, with WSL v1 it doesn't matter at all whether Hyper-V is enabled, it runs entirely on the (Windows) NT kernel with no virtualization. There are other Windows features that use virtualization, mostly for security reasons, but you almost certainly aren't using them as they're mainly targeted at businesses.